# obscure flask html alert - "the following data would have been submitted to the server"

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

**Intro**: i am developing a python flask web application with jquery-3.3.1. At the same time i am also using datatables 1.10. so in data table there is an option to convert the table data into csv/pdf/excel and download them so whenever i click them, am getting this alert. FYI, most the db callings are being done asynchronously using ajax calls.
[image: alert]

**My problem in detail**: If i am not wrong this alert comes up when a submit button tag is clicked, for this reason i have stopped using buttons tags instead going with div tags and putting an onclick event trigger function for the same. but when it comes to datatable, as it injects its own buttons, i cant really change them(and i dont want to change it in the library source code).
Instead i have tried to curb the alert by putting a

> event.preventDefault()

like this

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

but this event is not even getting triggered.

**My Questions**

1. When does this alert occur (what and who triggers this)
2. any solutions for my needs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any solution to this yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it that way, removing the `<button>`

```php
@foreach ( $usuarios as $item)
<tr>
    <td>{{$item->id }}</td>
    <td>{{$item->name }}</td>
    <td>{{$item->email }}</td>
    <td>{{$item->id_departamento }}</td>
    <td>{{$item->id_perfil }}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a> 
      <a href="https://www.google.com.br" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</a>
    </td>
    </tr>                               
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Same error showup to me and spent hours trying to reslove it. in my page I was using a form and bootstrap table. I've tried everything. at last when I changed the form submission from `button` tag to `input type="submit"` tag it worked perfectly.